How does the program change the size of the tensor?
Why does the onnx model create a tensor with size (1,16,16,48) into the zf variable in the Init method. and in the Update method it requires that the tensor be (1,8,8,48)?
Below is the code.
void NanoTrack::init(cv::Mat img, cv::Rect bbox) 
{
    create_window();
    create_grids();

    cv::Point target_pos; // cx, cy
    cv::Point2f target_sz = {0.f, 0.f}; //w,h

    target_pos.x = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;  
    target_pos.y = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2; 
    target_sz.x=bbox.width;
    target_sz.y=bbox.height;
    
    float wc_z = target_sz.x + cfg.context_amount * (target_sz.x + target_sz.y);
    float hc_z = target_sz.y + cfg.context_amount * (target_sz.x + target_sz.y);
    float s_z = round(sqrt(wc_z * hc_z));  

    cv::Scalar avg_chans = cv::mean(img);
    cv::Mat z_crop;
    
    z_crop  = get_subwindow_tracking(img, target_pos, cfg.exemplar_size, int(s_z),avg_chans); //cv::Mat BGR order 

    ncnn::Extractor ex_backbone = net_backbone.create_extractor();
    
    ex_backbone.set_light_mode(true); 
    ex_backbone.set_num_threads(16); 
    
    ncnn::Mat ncnn_img = ncnn::Mat::from_pixels(z_crop.data, ncnn::Mat::PIXEL_BGR2RGB, z_crop.cols, z_crop.rows);
    
    // NanoTrack跟踪器不需要使用均值和方差 
    // ncnn_img.substract_mean_normalize(this->mean_vals, this->norm_vals);

    ex_backbone.input("input", ncnn_img);
    ex_backbone.extract("output", zf);
    
    this->state.channel_ave=avg_chans;
    this->state.im_h=img.rows;
    this->state.im_w=img.cols;
    this->state.target_pos=target_pos;
    this->state.target_sz= target_sz;  
}

int NanoTrack::draw(cv::Mat& rgb)
{
//    if(!this->is_init)
//    {
//        rgb.copyTo(temp);//初始化图像
//    }

    rgb.copyTo(temp); //保存图像随时用于初始化模版

    cv::rectangle(rgb, cv::Rect(this->state.target_pos.x - this->state.target_sz.x / 2, this->state.target_pos.y - this->state.target_sz.y / 2, this->state.target_sz.x, this->state.target_sz.y),
                  cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, 8);
    return 0;
    //return 0;
}

void NanoTrack::update(const cv::Mat &x_crops, cv::Point &target_pos, cv::Point2f &target_sz,  float scale_z, float &cls_score_max)
{

    ncnn::Mat ncnn_img = ncnn::Mat::from_pixels(x_crops.data, ncnn::Mat::PIXEL_BGR2RGB, x_crops.cols, x_crops.rows);
    
    // 我们训练的 NanoTrack 不需要计算均值和方差  
    // ncnn_img.substract_mean_normalize(this->mean_vals, this->norm_vals);

    ncnn::Extractor ex_backbone=net_backbone.create_extractor();

    ex_backbone.set_light_mode(true); 
    ex_backbone.set_num_threads(1);
    
    //#if NCNN_VULKAN
    //    std::cout << NCNN_VULKAN << std::endl;
    //    ex_backbone.opt.use_vulkan_compute = True;
    //#endif 
    
    ex_backbone.input("input",ncnn_img);
    ex_backbone.extract("output",xf); 

    ncnn::Extractor ex_head = net_head.create_extractor();
    ex_head.set_light_mode(true); 
    ex_head.set_num_threads(16); // 16 
    
    ex_head.input("input1", zf); // 8,8,1,48
    ex_head.input("input2", xf); // 16,16,1,48  注意,如果输入的大小不对会导致 ex_neck_head.extract 过程报错
    
    ncnn::Mat cls_score, bbox_pred; 
    ex_head.extract("output1", cls_score);  
    ex_head.extract("output2", bbox_pred); 
    
    std::vector<float> cls_score_sigmoid; 
    
    // float* cls_score_data = (float*)cls_score.data; 
    float* cls_score_data = cls_score.channel(1); 

    cls_score_sigmoid.clear();  

    int cols = cls_score.w;  
    int rows = cls_score.h;   

    for (int i = 0; i < cols*rows; i++)   //
    {        
        cls_score_sigmoid.push_back(sigmoid(cls_score_data[i]));
    }

    std::vector<float> pred_x1(cols*rows, 0), pred_y1(cols*rows, 0), pred_x2(cols*rows, 0), pred_y2(cols*rows, 0);

    float* bbox_pred_data1 = bbox_pred.channel(0); 
    float* bbox_pred_data2 = bbox_pred.channel(1); 
    float* bbox_pred_data3 = bbox_pred.channel(2); 
    float* bbox_pred_data4 = bbox_pred.channel(3); 
    
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++)
        {

            pred_x1[i*cols + j] = this->grid_to_search_x[i*cols + j] - bbox_pred_data1[i*cols + j];
            pred_y1[i*cols + j] = this->grid_to_search_y[i*cols + j] - bbox_pred_data2[i*cols + j];
            pred_x2[i*cols + j] = this->grid_to_search_x[i*cols + j] + bbox_pred_data3[i*cols + j];
            pred_y2[i*cols + j] = this->grid_to_search_y[i*cols + j] + bbox_pred_data4[i*cols + j];
        }
    }

    // size penalty  
    std::vector<float> w(cols*rows, 0), h(cols*rows, 0); 
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++) 
        {
            w[i*cols + j] = pred_x2[i*cols + j] - pred_x1[i*cols + j];
            h[i*rows + j] = pred_y2[i*rows + j] - pred_y1[i*cols + j];
        }
    }

    float sz_wh = sz_whFun(target_sz);
    std::vector<float> s_c = sz_change_fun(w, h, sz_wh);
    std::vector<float> r_c = ratio_change_fun(w, h, target_sz);

    std::vector<float> penalty(rows*cols,0);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
    {
        penalty[i] = std::exp(-1 * (s_c[i] * r_c[i]-1) * cfg.penalty_k);
    }

    // window penalty
    std::vector<float> pscore(rows*cols,0);
    int r_max = 0, c_max = 0; 
    float maxScore = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
    {
        pscore[i] = (penalty[i] * cls_score_sigmoid[i]) * (1 - cfg.window_influence) + this->window[i] * cfg.window_influence; 
        if (pscore[i] > maxScore) 
        {
            // get max 
            maxScore = pscore[i]; 
            r_max = std::floor(i / rows); 
            c_max = ((float)i / rows - r_max) * rows;  
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << "pscore_window max score is: " << pscore[r_max * cols + c_max] << std::endl;

    // to real size
    float pred_x1_real = pred_x1[r_max * cols + c_max]; // pred_x1[r_max, c_max]
    float pred_y1_real = pred_y1[r_max * cols + c_max];
    float pred_x2_real = pred_x2[r_max * cols + c_max];
    float pred_y2_real = pred_y2[r_max * cols + c_max];

    float pred_xs = (pred_x1_real + pred_x2_real) / 2;
    float pred_ys = (pred_y1_real + pred_y2_real) / 2;
    float pred_w = pred_x2_real - pred_x1_real;
    float pred_h = pred_y2_real - pred_y1_real;

    float diff_xs = pred_xs - cfg.instance_size / 2;
    float diff_ys = pred_ys - cfg.instance_size / 2;

    diff_xs /= scale_z; 
    diff_ys /= scale_z;
    pred_w /= scale_z;
    pred_h /= scale_z;

    target_sz.x = target_sz.x / scale_z;
    target_sz.y = target_sz.y / scale_z;

    // size learning rate
    float lr = penalty[r_max * cols + c_max] * cls_score_sigmoid[r_max * cols + c_max] * cfg.lr;

    // size rate
    auto res_xs = float (target_pos.x + diff_xs);
    auto res_ys = float (target_pos.y + diff_ys);
    float res_w = pred_w * lr + (1 - lr) * target_sz.x;
    float res_h = pred_h * lr + (1 - lr) * target_sz.y;

    target_pos.x = int(res_xs);
    target_pos.y = int(res_ys);

    target_sz.x = target_sz.x * (1 - lr) + lr * res_w;
    target_sz.y = target_sz.y * (1 - lr) + lr * res_h;

    cls_score_max = cls_score_sigmoid[r_max * cols + c_max];
}

when writing your own program using nanotrack_backbone_sim.onnx and nanotrack_head_sim.onnx
there is a conflict between tensor sizes.
